# Смена блока на странице через Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Имеется меню - nav, в нём ссылки через href. Так же имеется контент по центру - main. Как сделать так, что бы при нажатии на ссылку в nav менялся лишь main. Знаю что через Ajax это делается, но не могу найти код который бы мог это реализовать.
NAV - это отдельный файл, который я подключал через include.

```
<a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#news"
                   aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseLayouts">
                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon">
                        <i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i>
                    </div>
                    Новости
                    <div class="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow">
                        <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="collapse" id="news" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                     data-parent="#sidenavAccordion">
                    <nav class="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/news">Главная</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="../add/add_news.php">Добавить</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
```

MAIN:

```
<main lass="animate__animated animate__bounceInDown">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h1 class="mt-4 p-3">Новости</h1>
                <?php if (mysqli_num_rows($news) > 0): ?>
                    <div class="col">
                        <nav>
                            <ul class="pagination justify-content-lg-end">
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="/news.php?page=<?= $Previous; ?>" tabindex="-1"
                                       aria-disabled="true">
                                        <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++): ?>
                                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"
                                                             href="/news.php?page=<?= $i; ?>"><?= $i; ?></a></li>
                                <?php endfor; ?>
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="/news.php?page=<?= $Next; ?>" tabindex="-1"
                                       aria-disabled="true">
                                        <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if (mysqli_num_rows($news) > 0):foreach ($news

                as $row): ?>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card mb-4 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" style="max-width: 99%;">
                        <div class="row g-8">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <?php
                                if ($row['photo']) {
                                    echo '<img class="img-thumbnail" src="' . $row['photo'] . '">';
                                } else {
                                    echo '<img class="card-img" alt="' . $row['title'] . '" src="smile.png">';
                                }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h3 class="card-title"><?= $row['title'] ?></h3>
                                    <p class="card-text"><?= $row['text'] ?></p>
                                    <br>
                                    <hr>
                                    <?php
                                    if ($row['url']) {
                                        echo '<p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted"><a href="' . $row['url'] . '" target="_blank">Ссылка на источник...</a></small></p>';
                                    }
                                    if ($row['data']) {
                                        echo '<p class="card-header-tabs"><small class="text-muted">Дата публикации: ' . $row['data'] . '</small></p>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="container p-4 m-3">
                                        <p class="text-muted text-right float-right">
                                            <a href="/edit/edit_news.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"
                                               class="btn btn-outline-success">Редактировать
                                            </a>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <?php endforeach; else: ?>
                        <div class="card text-center"
                             style='margin: 4rem;padding: 3rem;'>
                            <h3>В данный момент новостей нету.</h3>
                            <br>
                            <a href="add/add_news.php" class="btn btn-outline-success">Добавить</a>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.nav-link').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'урл до файла с логикой',
      success: function(data) {
        $('.animate__animated').html(data);
      }
    });
});
```

У ссылок соответственно нужно убрать href

Comment: А что нужно писать в 'урл до файла с логикой'? Сам main?

Comment: всё, понял.. спасибо)